# How can I make a variable for every user in discord bot. discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have a bot, and want to make seperate variables for a user in discord.py.
Ex) If one guy is Bob and The other is Ted, Bob may have 100 coins, but ted only 5. This would also apply to any extra users that join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to create a class for users and then make a list of User instances:

```py
# definition of the User class
class User():
    def __init__(self, name: str, coins: int):
        self.name = name
        self.coins = coins
    
    def addCoins(self, amount: int):
        self.coins += amount
    
# You could also put them into a dictionary - it's up to you how you want to store them.
# In this case I'm just using a list for simplicity.

users = []
users.append(User("Bob", 100))
users.append(User("Ted", 5))
    
# print Bob's coins
print(users[0].coins)
    
# 100
    
# print Ted's coins
print(users[1].coins)
    
# 5
    
# add coins to Ted's account
users[1].addCoins(10)
    
# print Ted's coins again
print(users[1].coins)
    
# 15
```

I can recommend looking into lists, dictionaries and loops if you haven't already done so.